# Moles and System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, moles

I'm trying Moles for the first time. When I try to add a Moles assembly on System.Windows.Forms it generates code with references to System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection and IReadOnlyList which doesn't compile because they are only in .NET Framework 4.5 and my projects are all 4.0 in VS2010. I've set the assembly references to specific versions but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Why you want to add Moles to WinForms? Normally you should reference it in your Unit test projects.

Comment: But what you mention is strange because Moles is for VS 2010 in VS 2012 you need to use Fakes afaik. So it doesn't make sense that moles needs references to .Net Fx 4.5 classes.

Comment: @Dannydust The code I'm testing is the config UI for a BizTalk adapter. It's just a dll that is run by the BizTalk framework in MMC so I've got it calling MessageBox.Show to display any errors to the user. I want to test the rest of the functionality but mock this call. It's BizTalk 2010 which is only supported in Visual Studio 2010 so I can't use Fakes. I don't even have VS2012 installed.

Comment: What about replacing the call to MessageBox.Show with an Action<string> to avoid this dependency? The caller itself should pass then (str) => MessageBox.Show(str) as a parameter. It's not a solution but a workaround. I do it very often in my code, so different callers can pass different logic (Show a MessageBox, Write a log entry,...)

Comment: Well that would be normal dependency injection which is fine for this scenario but I thought Moles could do this so wanted to know why not. If I can't rely on it to be able to do runtime instrumentation then I will give it a miss.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I can't help you any further I will upvote your Question to get more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Moles in Visual Studio 2012, you will need to explicitly exclude certain assemblies and types.

Here's what works for me:

```
<Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms" ReflectionOnly="true"/>
<StubGeneration>
    <Types>
        <Clear />
        <Add FullName="Your.Type.Full.Name!" />
    </Types>
</StubGeneration>
<MoleGeneration>
    <Types>
        <Clear />
        <Add FullName="Your.Type.Full.Name!" />
    </Types>
</MoleGeneration>
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to this. That does work. Thanks.